# Closure of the interior of the closure of the interior

Tags: math-mode

I'm writing an exercise about the [Kuratowski closure-complement problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_closure-complement_problem).

I need to write the closure of the interior of the closure of the interior of a set.

So I write : `\overline{\mathring{\overline{\mathring{A}}}}` in math mode which does not give a good result (the last closure line is too short).

Can you help me?

Comment: You don't like how `\bar{\mathring{\bar{\mathring{A}}}}` looks? In any case, *define symbolic names*! Your code should, at least, look like `\closure{\interior{\closure{\interior{A}}}}`.

Comment: For this example, it would be ok. But if you replace A by a longer set (like B(x_0, R_1)), the closure with \bar is really small.

Comment: VERY unexpected behaviour!

Comment: @user37238 You could change your name to something more telling. You can program those commands to act differently depending on what's in their argument.

Comment: Is it the upper `\overline` that is too short or the lower that is too long? Compare `$\overline{\mathring{A}}\ \mathring{\overline{\mathring{A}}}$`

Comment: Typesetting puzzles are fun but you're best off using a notation like say `$kikiA$` to represent the closure of the interior of the closure of the interior of `$A.$`

Answer (score 2):

Add a little bit of space before doing the last overline:

```
$\overline{\,\mathring{\overline{\mathring{A}}}\,}$
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, define `\closure` and `\interior` (or shorter names if you want) and use those symbolic definitions, this way, you can *program* things into the macros.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\closure{sm}
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\overline{#2}}{\bar{#2}}}
\NewDocumentCommand\interior{sm}
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{?}{\mathring{#2}}{}}

\begin{document}
$\closure{\interior{\closure{\interior{A}}}}$ and $\closure*{B(x_0,R_1)}$
\end{document}
```

I leave an `?` in a situation in which I don't know what you want (some people write it like `(...)^\circ` and other put an overparentheses (`\overparen` may be, or may be a self defined macro) and then a `\mathring` over the parenthesis, etc.).

On a side note, may be, depending on your documment, you might want to define something like *open-ball* `\oB` and *closed-ball* `\cB` and use like `\cB(x_0,R_1)` in which case it's easy to change the definition of those commands whenever you want, and you are not stuck with the raw code.

Answer (score 0):

By inserting something to the right in the last `\overline` it is stretch to the end. I tried some different combinations and with

```
\overline{\mathring{\overline{\mathring{A}}}\phantom{.}}
```

I get

[image]

It is still just a fix and not an answer to why it behaves like it does from the beginning.