# Unexpected behaviour of `\overline`

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath

This is in some sense continuation of [Closure of the interior of the closure of the interior](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329166/closure-of-the-interior-of-the-closure-of-the-interior)

As we can see `\overline{\mathring{\overline{\mathring{A}}}}` produces the second line **shorter** than the first (inner) one.  More horizontal material should give longer box, hence longer line over it. Because `\overline` is a primitive, I have no acces to its definition now. It is difficult to believe that it may be bug in TeX, so why so unexpected shortening of the line over?

Comment: The following, `\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt\relax
\setbox0=\hbox{$\overline{\mathring{A}}$}
\fbox{$\copy0$}
\fbox{$\overline{\mathring{\box0}}$}
$\overline{\mathring{\overline{\mathring{A}}}}$
\end{document}` doesn't explain *why*, but certainly shows something of what is happening

Comment: Hve you tried with other accents? Accents and stacking accents in general tend to have some weird behaviour.

Comment: @Manuel No, I have tried boxing, and even Steven B. Segletes' example contradicts my expectations.

Comment: note the question is really more about `\mathring` than `\overline` (the overline is just showing the width of the accent construct) and `\mathring` is a latex command so as it stands the [tag:tex-core] and [tag:plain-tex] tags are probably not appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

amsmath

[image]

no amsmath

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 

$\overline{\mathring{\overline{\mathring{A}}}}$ 

\bigskip

$\overline{\mathring{\overline{\mathring{{}A{}}}}}$ 

\end{document}
```

*Without* `amsmath` the two example above produce the same sized bars. With `amsmath` the math accent tries to be smarter about allowing for italic correction. but it can only do that if the base is a single character.

Comment: It is very interesting clue.

Answer (score 2):

This can hopefully be seen both as an attempt to answer the question and as a comment to David Carlisle's answer. I would say amsmath does compensate for italic also for the second accent. In amsmath `\mathring` checks if there are nested accents, and if so adds some extra (artificial or temporary) space so the second ring is centered above the first. Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\defmathring\mathring
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent
%%
$\mathring{\mathring{A}} \quad \defmathring{\defmathring{A}}$
%%
\newline\strut\newline
%%
$\overline{\mathring{A}} \quad \overline{\defmathring{A}}$
%%
\newline\strut\newline
%%
$\mathring{\overline{\mathring{A}}} \quad \defmathring{\overline{\defmathring{A}}}$
\end{document}
```

Then `\defmathring` is the definition for `\mathring` when amsmath is not loaded.

[image]

In the first column of the output amsmath is used, and in the second the default without. In the first row two rings are used and if amsmath is loaded they are aligned. In the third row there is an `\overline` added in between the two rings. Since there are nested rings the lower has an extra width to the right. This will center the second ring above it, but, as a side effect, it will also make the `\overline` expand out to the right.

The second row just shows one ring with an `\overline`. Then there are no nested accents and the spacing is not changed.